# Как перерисовать QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть QgraphicsView который содержит несколько QgraphicsItem. Как перерисовать сцену после того как я поменял координаты QgraphicsItem?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#updateScene

Comment: Она вроде бы сама перерисовывается, если были изменения позиций или трансформаций элементов. Возможно, вам нужно обновить не саму сцену, а видимый прямоугольник? `scene()->setSceneRect(scene()->itemsBoundingRect()`

Comment: Еще может быть проблема с масштабированием, лечится вызовом `view->fitInView(view->scene()->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);` после загрузки всех элементов сцены или в `QGraphicsView::resizeEvent`. Ну или нужен более сложный механизм масштабирования.

Comment: Все получилось. QGraphicsItem->update(). Я до этого не правильно координаты устанавливал.